# Run C++ program in Terminal

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run this simple C++ code in Sublime Text on Terminal but it's not exactly working...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I'm getting this message instead:

> "hello_world2.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found"

How can I fix this?

Comment: running and compiling are two separate things. That sounds like a compiler error, and your compiler settings are incorrect and cannot find the standard library.

Comment: You have to compile this code into an executeable (a program that can be run).

Comment: FYI, [Using Sublime Text As Your IDE](https://www.chromium.org/developers/sublime-text).

Answer (score 2):

You most probably are missing development headers for your C++ standard library.

You didn't say anything about your environment, but if you were on Windows on Mac you would for sure get these together with your compiler, so let's assume Linux.

- You need to install `libstdc++-devel` package or equivalent (`libstdc++-4.8-dev` etc.)